# ActionBar Behavior

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I know there are lots of question regarding Action bar. And may be my question does not require code sample, but this is purely coding stuff.

How  do android take decision that in action bar it need to show TABS or List. My question is strictly on android 4.0  and above, whether smart phone or tablet. 
Is there some way we can find out that device will be showing Spinner or tabs in action bar.
My question arised when i was deploying my app to Google nexus and Samsung Tab2.  In tab I was getting action bar as List in portrait mode and as tab in landscape mode. While i observed opposite in Google Nexus. *NOTE* This happens when I set my Navigation mode as Tab `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

My question is simple and straight, How Android decide to show List or Tab in action bar.??
and how Developer can check whether List mode will shown or Tab will be shown in action bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can assume and find that android by itself check for the compact mode and show spinner and tabs accordingly. Not a satisfactory answer but I don't have any thing else to think and find.Any answer with better explanation is acceptable and welcome.

if `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` is set post 4.0 android will check whether enough space is available to show tabs or not. If its not then it transfers tabs to spinner(As drop down).